How to configure Github actions to store terraform state in one account and apply changes in another account using AWS?
I have the below github actions workflow:
   - name: Configure AWS Credentials
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
    with:
      aws-region: 'us-east-1'
      role-to-assume: 'assume_role_for_account_A"
      role-duration-seconds: 3600
    - name: Terraform Init
      id: init
      run: |
        terraform init \
        -backend-config="key= account_b.tfstate" \
        -backend-config="bucket='test-bucket' \
        -backend-config="encrypt=true" \
        -backend-config="profile=s3_backend"
    - name: Terraform Plan
      id: plan
      run: terraform plan -no-color -input=false  

In the terraform provider config, I am specifying role to assume for AccountB and the region. How can I store terraform backend config in account a and deploy resources in account B?
Trying to implement this: https://www.padok.fr/en/blog/terraform-s3-bucket-aws

Are there any errors? Is something not working here? How does the provider configuration look like?
